# How do I scrape Dynamic content from Woolworths catalogue? Can't seem to find the price and product class

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to attain Woolworth specials data from this website: "https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/catalogue"
However, I can't seem to extract the specific class information I am after. Examples include: 'sf-pricedisplay', 'shelfProductStamp-imageTagsContainer' and etc. They are contained within a container. 
I believe this information may be generated dynamically.

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/catalogue#view=catalogue2&saleId=28314&areaName=NSW&page=3")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all('div', class_='shop-content'))  # This works.
```

Comment: When I go to the link no specials seem to load? Does one have to input an area for that to display; and if so, have you accounted for it in the script?

Comment: That is a really good point. I didn't realise. I will give that a go. I have also changed the link now.

Comment: The link you have shared is not working without providing postcode

Comment: I cannot figure out how to provide the website with the suburb/location. It doesn't appear in the URL.

Comment: Woolworths intentionally make it difficult to scape their products and site to prevent cross comparison by competitors. They have API's but only for Woolworth employees with cause to access.

I have been able to get the catalog content but am unable to parse the data correctly because the response I get has escape characters for their JS rendering.

Try this url for the contents of the Wed 23 Aug - Tue 29 Aug 2023 NSW 2750 catalog.  https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/catalogue/view#view=list&saleId=51575&areaName=NSW